# Loading data using data loader

Tags: workflow, administration, data-loader, field-update

I have a scenario where I want to just edit and save bunch of records without actually editing any fields or data in that record. I want to do this because the workflow rule associated with this record triggers only when it is created as new or edited.

I would like to know if I use data loader to export and import the records again would the workflow rule trigger in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your workflow evaluation criteria is set to `created, and every time it's edited` and not `created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria` you can do an export with data loader of just the IDs, and then do an update of the same list and the workflow will execute, assuming it meets the criteria for the workflow rule.